# Getting null pointer exception from dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting `NullPointerException` while calling a method:
Xgenexport.java

```
Map agent_Details = commonLookupDAO.getAgentDetails(dQuoteDetails.getAgentId());
```

And the method in: 
Commonlookup dao:

```
public Map getAgentDetails(String agentId);
```

Commonlookupdaoimpl

```
public Map getAgentDetails(String agentId) {
    /*some code*/
    return resultMap;
}
```

Im getting `NullPointerException` while calling this method don't know the exact reason.

Comment: So what exactly is at the line `XGenExportmotorcycle.java:281`? Is it the code which you posted first? If so, post a little more code, like where the Dao is injected.

Comment: yes that were i got null pointer exception

Comment: my case is different this is not duplicate

Comment: how you are creating obect `commonLookupDAO`

Comment: @mike - No.  Your case is the same.  That Q & A gives a >>general<< explanation of what an NPE is and a >>general<< approach to solving the problem.  You apply it to your particular problem.

Comment: And for what it is worth, you have not shown us any evidence that would help us help you anyway.  You need to 1) show us the stack trace, 2) show us the relevant code, 3) identify clearly the line of code at which the exception was thrown.

Comment: No i got little bit confused when im using a return type as string i can acces this method

Comment: Now you are getting incomprehensible ......

Comment: that means can you explain clearly

Comment: show your code as asked by Stephen C

Comment: if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(dQuoteDetails.getAgentId())){
     Map agent_details = commonLookupDAO.getAgentDetails(dQuoteDetails.getAgentId());
    }

Comment: Im getting null pointer when im calling getAgentdetails

Comment: Method in Commonlookupdaoimpl:

Comment: public Map getAgentDetails(String agentId) {
  LOGGER.info("agent details starts :::::::::");
  Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  String oa_code = "";
  String ag_code = "";
  Map resultMap = new HashedMap();
  try{
   SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("Select OA_CODE,AG_CODE from AGENT_MASTER where AGENT_ID= :agentId");
   query.setParameter("agentId", agentId);
   List query_list = query.list();

Comment: when i changed the return type to String im not getting any exception.it works fine..

Comment: if any body can't understand my code plz revert me so that i can do the possible note..

Answer (score 0):

how you are creating obect `commonLookupDAO`

using `Spring` you may need to use `Autowire` it, if you are creating `Single` object of `DAO class`

Comment: Show me your controller

Comment: I used autowired only